# Gulpfile fails to run in VS 2019 - node.js. Error present in VS2019, not in 2017. Why?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, gulp

loading my project in VS2019 i get the error as in the picture below.
Loading the project in VS 2017, i do not get this error.

[image]

Running the gulpfile manually, it is ok like this, proving that there is no error with the file:
[image]

Starting the project (Launching the local Web-server), the solution will run, and web-site start.
But the error is very annoying, how can i fix the error? It must be VS2019 configuration that is off/wrong somewhere?

Running gulp -v in the local repo:
[image]
And comparing with project package.sjon: [image]

And in solution tree: [image]

There is a difference, but that should be equal for VS2017...?
Or is there a conflict?

**I have tried:**

Adding a specific path: [Task Runner Explorer window had "failed to load" under my Gulpfile.js and none of the build processes were listed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076486/task-runner-explorer-window-had-failed-to-load-under-my-gulpfile-js-and-none-o)

Installed gulp globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating gulp from 3.9.1 to 4.0.2 solved this for me. Dont know why VS-2019 would complain about this.
I had some bluescreens after a windows-update during (unsaved) work on this solution some days ago. So maybe some corruption of files etc...
Updateing in this context means

1. To uninstall 3.9.1
2. Install 4.0.2